# Value is not show up in input form

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning and practicing with javascript, I try to **calculate the volume of sphere**, but it does not show the value in the **input form**. I do not know where I miss or wrong code, can anyone help me, I am new in Javascript. Thank you so much

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <title>Calculate</title>
      </head>

      <body>
         volume of a sphere
         <form action="">
            Enter radius: <input type="text" name = "radius" id="radius">

            Volume: <input type="text" name="volume" id="volume">
            <input type = "submit" onclick="calculate()" value="Calculate">
         </form>
     </body>
   <script src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
 </html>
```

This is my js code

```
function calculate(){
     var radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
     var volume = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);

     document.getElementById("volume").value = volume.toFixed(4).;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a syntax error in last line of your function. So, I made the correction and here it is:

```js
function calculate(){
     var radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
     var volume = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);

     document.getElementById("volume").value = volume.toFixed(4);
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript: void(0);">
    Enter radius: <input type="text" name = "radius" id="radius">

    Volume: <input type="text" name="volume" id="volume">
    <input type = "submit" onclick="calculate()" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

If you see the `action` attribute, I have added the javascript there. Just to handle the default work of form. If you remove that line `javascript: void(0);`, your calculated value will be seen just for few milliseconds and will submit the form.

*Note: Always check the console if you do not get the expected out put. To check console you inspect element and select the console tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your script tag is outside the body. It should be inside like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <title>Calculate</title>
      </head>

      <body>
         volume of a sphere
         <form action="">
            Enter radius: <input type="text" name = "radius" id="radius">

            Volume: <input type="text" name="volume" id="volume">
            <input type = "submit" onclick="calculate()" value="Calculate">
         </form>
         <script src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of stuffs

- You are using a form with a submit, so when you press the button the form is refreshed, that would clean any compute you do. You need to take off the form.
- Your java script has an error, an additional point here volume.toFixed(4).; that point between the ) and the semicolon

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is an extra . in your js code needs to be removed from line 4

```js
     document.getElementById("volume").value = volume.toFixed(4);
```

and the volume is not showing because when you hit submit button your submit the form and send a get request that refreshes your page so the data is not shown

to solve this you have two options:

1- place the button outside the form

```html
         <form action="">
            Enter radius: <input type="text" name = "radius" id="radius">

            Volume: <input type="text" name="volume" id="volume">
         </form>
            <input type = "button" onclick="calculate()" value="Calculate">
```

but in this context it is meaningless to set the input button type to submit
instead use button
2- try using prevent default from js code

```js
document.getElementById("calculateButton").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
})

function calculate() {

    var radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
    var volume = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);

    document.getElementById("volume").value = volume.toFixed(4);
}
```